# panel header change colour on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have this button that changes the colour of my site, (text etc etc) i'm wanting to change the background colour of the panel header.

Currently the button works on AFO. Heres the stylesheet for it

```
.AFO { background-color: #fff;}
.AFO h1 { color: #00159d; }
.AFO h2 { color: #00159d; }
.AFO h3 { color: #00159d; }
.AFO h4 { color: #00159d; }
.AFO h5 { color: #00159d; }
.AFO h6 { color: #00159d; }
.AFO p { color: #00159d; }
.AFO th { background-color: #c3cced; color: #00159d;}
.AFO panel-header { background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3cced, #00159d ) !important; color: #00159d !important;}
```

The HTML
`<div class="panel-heading orange ct-orange" ng-class="colorScheme">Details</div>`

i have the button working, I'd show you the javascript but i cant find it :(

When i inspect element the AFO gets added onto the end of the class, It is quite persistant in staying orange (its original colour)

So far, The only way i have been able to change the panel colour is via changing top line to this in the css
`.AFO { background-color: #fff; background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3cced, #00159d ) !important; color: #00159d !important;}`

Any ideas would be great! Just let me know if your needing something, I'll continue the search for the button!!!

Found the JS

```
    $(function() {
  $(".colorSelect").change(function() {
    $("body").attr('class', '');
    $(".colorSelect").each(function() {
      $("body").addClass($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add the `.` to target that `class` element

**From**

```
.AFO panel-header { background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3cced, #00159d ) !important; color: #00159d !important;}
```

**To**

```
.AFO .panel-header { background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3cced, #00159d ) !important; color: #00159d !important;}
```

**Update**

Since `AFO` is being added on that element use `.AFO.panel-header` without space instead of just `.AFO .panel-header`.

```
.AFO.panel-header { background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3cced, #00159d ) !important; color: #00159d !important;}
```

**Update**

Name of the class is `panel-heading` and not `panel-header`

Your css should have this instead:

```
.AFO.panel-heading { background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3cced, #00159d ) !important; color: #00159d !important;}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whebstyu/2/)

Comment: Still didn't work, even if i go into inspect element and manually try to make it work it doesnt e.g. remove orange reverts it back to the original panel colour

Comment: @ddsbro hmm ok, is the `AFO` class being added on this `<div class="panel-heading orange ct-orange" ng-class="colorScheme">Details</div>` element or on the parent container?

Comment: @ddsbro Updated post.

Comment: ha i've made i attach everywhere! heres my html once the buttons pressed `<div class="col-md-12 AFO" ng-class="colorScheme" style="">
      <div class="panel panel-default AFO" ng-class="colorScheme" style="">
<div class="panel-heading orange ct-orange AFO" ng-class="colorScheme" style="">Details</div>
<div class="panel-body ng-binding" ng-bind-html="eventData.description"></div>

  </div>
</div>`

Comment: found the js adding it now

Comment: @ddsbro hmm that's weird. It's possible that there's some styles overriding it. Can you check using inspect element? Or much better add a fiddle if possible, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Heres the JS fiddle, I cant seem to get the button working inside there. But the codes there https://jsfiddle.net/whebstyu/

Comment: @ddsbro oh the name of the class is `panel-heading` and not `panel-header`

Comment: @ddsbro Great! Haha glad it helped.